# Get UIImageView programmatically from View.

Tags: uiview, uiimageview

I'm creating a UIImageView within the code and I want to get it later on and set an image. How do I do this please help?

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
UIImageView *Game_ImageViews = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    Game_ImageViews.tag = x;
    [Game_View addSubview:Game_ImageViews];
}


            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]      
                                                                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.png"]];
        (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:100].image = image;
        [image release];
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewWithTag` will give you the view with the tag if a subview with that tag exists. So for example, your `self.view` would have to have a subview that has a tag of 100.

Initially, you are setting up subviews of `Game_View` with tags of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

So, to retrieve a subview by tag you would have to do, assuming you want to retrieve the view tagged by id `1`:

```
 ((UIImageView*)[Game_View viewWithTag:1]).image = image;
```

A couple of other things worth mentioning. You're not releasing `Game_ImageViews` in your loop above, so that will give a memory leak.

Also, if you use the `imageNamed` method of `UIImage`, that will give you a couple of benefits. First, you'll have a cached image which could improve performance. Secondly, you'll have an autoreleased object which saves you the bother of releasing it yourself. Unless of course you want maximum performance and control by doing it as you have done above.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I knew about the tag number being off within my code I just posted it wrong, but I did not catch that I was trying to get the image from the wrong view. Duh. Using dot notion does not work like you and I have there I guess because it needs to be converted to UIImageView. Has to be written like this: [(UIImageView*)[Game_View viewWithTag:1] setImage:image];

Comment: yes you're right about the syntax. I've added some parenthesis to fix that. You need to cast the UIView returned by viewWithTag to a UIImageView and then call the .image property on that.